# Is there a difference in behavior of applicationDidBecomeActive in iOS simulator and iDevice?

Tags: ios

I have this strange issue.

The applicationDidBecomeActive method is called correctly in the iOS simulator after quitting the app (putting in the background) but that does not happen in the iPhone.

SDK 4.3.3

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which iPhone are you using? Older iPhones incapable of iOS multitasking will not call this method. When sent to the background, the app is actually terminated on older iPhones.

Comment: OK. I figured out what was the reason. I had a Bonjour service broadcast and periodically update a TXTRecordData. The method didUpdateTXTRecordData was called OK in iOS simulator after reviving the app from the background but in the real device I had to call startMonitoring again. (I still do not know why) So I add it anyway and now it works on both.